# Error150 (net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN): The server's certificate appears to be a forgery

Tags: web-application, windows, google

Help me guys please i'm having an problem with my google account.
I can't log in it keeps saying :  Error 150 (net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN): The server's certificate appears to be a forgery.
How do i fix this please?

Comment: Welcome to security.stackexchange.com. You have not given us any details to work with nor told us what you have tried to fix the problem. You can also see that there is another post here with the same problem. Keep in mind that we are not a tech support site, but we do offer ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A quick [search](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/WCcmRXfuj0Y) indicates that you might see this if your Chrome version is very old.